# Error in re-connecting to ADB over wifi

Tags: android, adb

I am using android on ubuntu 13.04 and once when my usb cable was broken I searched SO for connecting android device over wifi and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2604727/1830763) helpful

It worked like charm but after few days when i was working again on android I tried connecting device through

```
adb connect 192.168.1.10
```

But got the error

```
Device not found
```

So I got new cable and tried through usb but that also didnt work

I tried

```
adb kill-server 
adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:7600
adb tcpip 7600
adb usb
```

But all end in same error

```
Device not found
```

Please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after uncountable tries I was able to make it work

I am answering for sake of sharing it with people who may need help in this

First I revoked usb authorization for all computer from mobile  ( I doubt if anything as such was there before 4.3 android)

Then I killed adb server

```
adb kill-server
```

Then I connected my mobile with laptop and invoked

```
adb usb
```

It gave me the following error

```
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

and in next moment I got a dialog on mobile for authorizing usb debugging

I allowed it and voila , it worked

Comment: I am following same..but it's not showing any Dialog...any suggestion?

Comment: @Shubh What was the output when you invoked "adb usb" command ?