# adb can't find device after failing to connect through WiFi

Tags: android, adb

Essentially, my problem is that I tried connecting my device to adb over Wifi, got to `adb connect xxx.xx.xx.xxx` but then adb claims that it was `unable to connect to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:5555`.

Ok, but now I'm having trouble getting it back to listening over USB. `adb usb` tells me that there isn't a device attached and `adb devices` gives me an empty list.

I've tried killing the adb server and then restarting it, toggling the device's debugging mode and toggling the device's USB storage transfer but nothing seems to be working. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317564/error-in-re-connecting-to-adb-over-wifi) seems very similar to my problem but I have no idea what the guy is doing in the solution.

I'm *guessing* the problem is that adb is still trying to listen through Wifi but since I can't connect to it over Wifi it can never go back to listening to it over USB. Idk...

Comment: Would restarting the device get it back to USB mode?  For wifi, you may be able to get it to work if you first use the browser on the device to visit a webpage or something and so effectively wake up the wifi radio and its connection to the access point; of course your access point will have to permit peer-to-peer traffic on the local subnet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton wow, opening up the browser actually worked...you want to put that in an answer? I feel like that could help people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wifi, you may be able to get it to work if you first use the browser on the device to visit a webpage or something and so effectively wake up the wifi radio and its connection to the access point.  You may need to keep doing this every once in a while.

(Maybe you should listen to internet radio while you work?)

Of course your access point will have to permit peer-to-peer traffic on the local subnet.  In many cases that may be the norm, but I believe an access point can be configured not to support that, and some may default to such settings.  There can also be issues between wired and wireless subnets sourced from the same box.

Finally, restarting the device might get it back into USB mode.